# Eclipse: ear recursively adds target folder while building

Tags: eclipse, compilation, ear

I've got a multimodule maven project (ejb,api,ear,web) contained beneath a main project. When the main project is rebuilt in Eclipse Juno (WTP, m2e installed on Win7 ), the ear submodule keeps adding the target folder in the ear project recursively to itself.

Adding target/** in the mvn-ear-plugin section does not help. So how do I exclude the target folder from being added recursively?